# How to prioritize an action (Make it go first) in Cocoa Touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, action

I'm learning objective-C programming for iOS, and I hit a small issue.  I'm building a fundamental RPN Calculator, and I'm trying to make it so that users can enter floating point numbers.  But, I need to prevent them from entering illegal floating point numbers (like 1324.343.34).  I tried adding a BOOL and an if statement but it got too messy, so I just added a separate action for if they pressed "."  Unfortunately though, even though the decimalPressed action is second, it still is going before the digit pressed action, and I need it to go after.  Any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];
    if (self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber) {
        if (self.dotPressed == NO || ([digit isEqualToString:@"."]==NO)) {
            self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingString:digit];
            self.dotPressed = NO;
        }
    } else {
        self.display.text = digit;
        self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)decimalPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.dotPressed = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you hooking up the buttons to their actions in code, or in Interface Builder?

You could change the "." button's `decimalPressed:` method to be called on "touch down inside" instead of "touch up inside". Make sure the `digitPressed:` method is called on "touch up inside".

This would ensure that `decimalPressed:` is called first, when the button is pressed down, then `digitPressed:` is called when the button is released.

You can do this either directly in code, or using Interface Builder in Xcode.

Comment: that would work, thanks.  But I feel like it just circumvents the problem, and it's more a learning question.  Like, if one button goes to two actions (or 3, 4, etc.) how do I chose which it goes to first?

Comment: I would assume that it calls them in the order you add the target/action. If you're using Interface Builder, I'd recommend removing the connections between your UI & buttons and try adding them in code using UIButton's: - (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents; Hope that helps!

Comment: Yea, I tried breaking the connections and adding them in the order that I want them to run, but without success.  I just changed the stuff done by the action, which solved the problem, but I still haven't learned how to do what I wanted to

Comment: UIKit doesn't make any guarantee regarding which action will be called first. It's a bad practice to rely on their order. You just need one action for the button and, inside that action, call the 2 methods that need to be in order.